# Motivation for Electric Displacement Field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

Here is the definition of the electric displacement field:

$\vec{D}≡\epsilon_0\vec{E}+\vec{P}$, where $-∇·\vec{P}=ρ_b$ and $\vec{P}$ is the electric dipole moment.

($ρ=ρ_f+ρ_b$, $ρ_f$ is free charge and $ρ_b$ is bound charge.)

How can we interpret the definition of $\vec{D}$ and $\vec{P}$?

Comment: Refer to David J. Griffiths's, Introduction to Electrodynamics chapter 4 of 4rth edition.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist: I will. Thank you for the suggested textbook!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf P$ is not the electric dipole moment of anything; it is, instead, the electric dipole moment *density*. So when you write $\rm {curl} \mathbf H = \mathbf J + \frac{\partial \mathbf P}{\partial t} + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}$ you can see that the rate of fluctuation of the dipole density is equivalent to a current density not just "conceptually" but also in its magnetic effect.

The "true" displacement current is just the term $\frac{\partial \mathbf P}{\partial t}$ and is called "displacement" because we view the true dipole moment fluctuation as being caused by the varying separation between two charges forming the dipole. In reality, there is no charge associated with the term $\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf E}{\partial t}$, it is a vacuum phenomenon without a deeper or more intuitive way to see it in classical EM.

Comment: Then $-∇⋅\vec{P}=ρ_b$ stems from Gauss law and divergence theorem, right?

Comment: The following statement of my textbook says: Demagnetizing field can be defined as:
$\vec{H}≡\frac{\vec{B}}{µ_0}-\vec{M}$ where $\vec{∇}×\vec{M}=\vec{J_b}$ ($\vec{J_b}$ is bound current). How can I get the formula of curl H above?

Comment: yes, the "source" of $\mathbf P$ is the bound charge, $\rm {div} \mathbf P = \rho_b$ and the missing term for charge conservation, $\rm {div} \mathbf J +\partial \rho/\partial t =0 $, is the term $\epsilon_0 \partial \mathbf E/\partial t$

Comment: *That* formula is for *magnetic* polarization and is not introduced to satisfy a conservation law as the term $\partial E/\partial t$ was invented for. Instead it is needed because there are two types of magnetic dipoles, one is a current loop (dynamic ) and the other is an inherent dipole (static). If you want to include $\mathbf J_b$ then just replace $\mathbf H$ with $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf M$ in $curl \mathbf H$; see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346025/what-is-the-strength-of-magnetic-flux-density-inside-a-magnet/346147#346147

Comment: @Hypotnex: I got it! Thank you so much!!